# SQL filtering out results based on a condition in two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement

I have a table with `q_type` and a `query` among other attributes as follows:

```
id, q_type, query, otherId
---------------------------
1, type1, mongo , 
2, type2, sql   , 
3, type1,       , 
4, type1, oracle,
5, type3,       , 23
6, type1,       ,
```

I would like to filter out rows having an empty `query` when `q_type='type1'` generating the following output:

```
    id, q_type, query, otherId
    ---------------------------
    1, type1, mongo , 
    2, type2, sql   , 
    4, type1, oracle,
    5, type3,       , 23
```

I think this requires a `CASE`, but was not able to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
where not (q_type = 'type1' and query is null)
```

Of course, you can expand this to:

```
where q_type <> 'type1' or query is not null
```

This assumes "empty" means `NULL`, but you can use similar logic for an empty string.

Comment: Yes, thank you! thought this required something more complex. I've been very slow today :(